# Ping retrieves an IP from DNS, but loses all packets

Tags: ip, dhcp, ping, gateway, redhat-enterprise-linux

I'm working with a minimal installation of RHEL 6.

When I first turned this machine on, it couldn't ping *anybody*.
It turned out that I needed to add the `GATEWAY` under `/etc/sysconfig/networking` and configure `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0` to point to the gateway and boot on start using DHCP.

As of now, I can access any other machine on the local network; I can even SSH into the machine I'm working with.
What I still cannot do is access anything outside of the local network; I can't access the internet.

Consider:

```
[root@dbrepa ~]# ping dev-108a -c 4
PING dev-108a.some.domain.net (192.168.108.119) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from dev-108a.some.domain.net (192.168.108.119): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.276 ms
64 bytes from dev-108a.some.domain.net (192.168.108.119): icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.249 ms
64 bytes from dev-108a.some.domain.net (192.168.108.119): icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.250 ms
64 bytes from dev-108a.some.domain.net (192.168.108.119): icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=0.259 ms

--- dev-108a.some.domain.net ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 4 received, 0% packet loss, time 3000ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.249/0.258/0.276/0.019 ms



[root@dbrepa ~]# ping example.com
PING example.com (93.184.216.119) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- example.com ping statistics ---
7 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 6741ms



[root@dbrepa ~]# route
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
192.168.108.0   *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
link-local      *               255.255.0.0     U     1002   0        0 eth0
default         dc-108a.cool.do 0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
```

`dev-108a` is a server on our network, and as you can see I can speak to it with no issues.
However, for `example.com`, I can retrieve the IP address from the DNS for `example.com`, in my case `93.184.216.119`, but then `ping` just *hangs*.
It's still working---it's still sending out packets, but none of them will get replies and this process will continue until kill.

As per the comments, I've brought the local firewall down (with `service iptables stop`) to no effect.

What could be going wrong?
How am I getting an IP address while not able to access it?

---

I know that I am missing several core UNIX tools; I am at least missing:

- `man`
- `dig`
- `traceroute`
- `telnet`
- `wget`

Comment: Please, provide output of 'route' command

Comment: name resolution is provided by DNS, even through ping.  Pings could be filtered, yet DNS lookups will still go through

Comment: @Nikolay Thanks, and done.  Note that `dc-108a` is our domain controller.

Comment: @Keltari yay learning! What could be filtering the pings? I brought the local firewall down (with `service iptables stop`) to no effect.  (I'll edit that into my Q.)

Comment: @vermiculus. Could you ping your default router and see if you able to reach it?

Comment: @Nikolay If router/gateway are the same thing (which my sysadmin guy says they are, at least for us) then yes I can.

Comment: Yes. In our case we are talking about host dc-108a.cool.do...

Comment: @Nikolay Yep, still can.

Answer (score 1):

```
'What could be going wrong? How am I getting an IP address while not able to access it?"
```

You are getting IP address because your computer can successfully reach the DNS server which your computer was instructed to use.

To make sure you can communicate to the outside of the network you need to make sure you have correct network settings including IP address, subnet mask and router.

If there is firewall operating at the gateway you have to make sure your computer was granted access from inside the network to the outside.

If can provide output of the following commands it will be possible to debug it faster:

```
ifconfig -a
route
```

Comment: I think you may be on to something with the subnet mask.  Do you know which file that is usually stored in?

Comment: Check if there is something in the /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/

Comment: Not that [I can see](http://i.stack.imgur.com/OVjiw.png).

Comment: Good. Open ifcfg-eth0 and see what is inside.

Comment: Everything [looks normal](http://i.stack.imgur.com/sZWz5.png).  Do I need to tell it anything else? (That's the entire contents of the file.)

Comment: No it is fine. You are getting your IP with DHCP. Can you show output of 'ifconfig -a'

Comment: Again, [nothing out of the ordinary](http://i.stack.imgur.com/y2jAQ.png), it seems.

Comment: Ok. One second.... You said 'It turned out that I needed to add the GATEWAY under /etc/sysconfig/networking'. Did you add this gateway information? Or gateway was set using DHCP as well?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10040/discussion-between-vermiculus-and-nikolay)